# How to add a CSS class to an element using a jQuery Selector?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am pretty new to JavaScript and jQuery and getting a little confused with "Selectors". Now I am sure you are all gurus and will find this trivial, so hoping you can help.

I have this HTML:

```
  <div class="class0">
    <div class="class1">
      <div class="class2">
        <div class="class3">Field 1:</div>
           <label class="class4">
               <input name="field" type="text" class="class5" />
           </label>
```

I am trying to addClasses to a number of elements but am getting stuck. I am trying to:

```
jQuery('.class0 input')
    .focus(function() {
    jQuery(this).parents('.class1').addClass("special_class");
    jQuery(this).parents('.class3').addClass("special_class_1");
    jQuery(this).parents('.class5').addClass("special_class_2");
```

But it doesn't seem to work - Class 1 does but the rest don't?

Comment: Please explain the context. What is "this" ?

Comment: What is `this` here? ie where is this being called?

Comment: @philippe, @Daniel 'this' here is the element that received focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are targeting one parent only then use .closest rather than parents.

Also if you know the node type of an element with a class it is always better to prefix the selector. In this case they all look like divs.

Try:

```
jQuery('div.class0 input').focus(function() {

    var $el= $(this);
    $el.closest('div.class1').addClass("special_class");
    $el.closest('div.class3').addClass("special_class_1");
    $el.closest('div.class5').addClass("special_class_2");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that should be:

```
jQuery('.class1').parents().addClass("special_class");
jQuery('.class3').parents().addClass("special_class_1");
jQuery('.class5').parents().addClass("special_class_2");
```

or even like this:

```
$('.class1').parents().addClass("special_class");
$('.class3').parents().addClass("special_class_1");
$('.class5').parents().addClass("special_class_2");
```

since $ variable is set to jQuery upon its initialization.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add 'new_class' to div with 'old_class' you should do something like this:

```
$('div.old_class').addClass('new_class');
```

If you want to add 'new_class' to parent of div with 'old_class' you should do something like this:

```
$('div.old_class').parent().addClass('new_class')
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the solution to change the class on those divs has been found but I think it needs to be pointed out that in your example above, the following is true:

1. input with class="class5" is the 'this' object, and not a parent so the selector when using parent('.class5') will not find it
2. In the hierarchy, the div with class="class3" gets closed and so is not a parent of 'input.class5'.  Rather, the div with class="class3" is a sibling of the label in your example.

So the following would have worked:

```
jQuery(this).parents('.class2').addClass("special_class_1");
```

Keep in mind the tree-like structure if you're going to use parent() or similar